# A unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{9}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that $1+3x$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z_9[x]$. Hence corollary 4.5 may be false if $R$ is not an integral domain.

The corollary 4.5 is:

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $f(x) \in R[x]$. Then $f(x)$ is a unit in $R[x]$ if and only if $f(x)$ is a constant polynomial that is a unit in $R$. In particular, if $F$ is a field, the units in $F[x]$ are the nonzero constants in $F$.

The biggest problem I am having is finding how what it means to be a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{9}[x]$. If I knew that I think I could figure it out from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unit of a (commutative) ring $R$ is an element $u \in R$ such that there exists $v \in R$ such that $$uv = vu = 1$$

Informally, the units of $R$ are the invertible elements of $R$ under the multiplication operation. With this in mind, a hint is: consider $1+6X \in (\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})[X]$.

Comment: Okay, I see that (1+6X)(1+3X)=1+9x+18x^2. Which would then be 1 in Zsub9[x]. Therefore, since there is an inverse for (1+3x) that also belongs in Z9, (1+3x) must be a unit.

Comment: @Lauren: yep, you got it!

Comment: -1 I'm sorry but I don't think this answer is helpful. You state the definition of a unit (which hopefully is already easy enough to find for the asker )and then give the inverse without any reasoning of how you came up with it. If I were to ask the asker how to find the inverse of $1+2x+24x^2$ in $\Bbb Z/64[x]$ do you think they would know what do just given this answer?

Comment: @PVAL: that's certainly fair, though I might have appreciated the chance to edit my answer based on your comment first. Nevertheless, you make a valid point, and my response is this: I wouldn't have mentioned the definition of a unit, had the OP not specifically asked. Regarding the inverse, I could see how I might not have really said enough, but I feel like one gets a good intuition for this sort of thing by looking at examples and then playing with others to generalize. The general statement is in Atiyah Macdonald, which I could mention, but I don't know how helpful it might be...

Comment: ...but regardless, I appreciate you taking the time to explain your thoughts.

Comment: @AlexWertheim I am allowed the opportunity to remove my downvote if there is a significant edit and will do so. The main point I am making is that if someone asks how to do something in some specific case then the answers should explain (or hint at) a method for finding out how to solve similar cases. Being able to construct the inverse of this element is the interesting part of the problem (multiplying two polynomials in a ring is not) and I'd hope that someone after solving this problem would know what to do in a case like I mentioned above whether or not they can prove the general case.

Answer (score 2):

First note that the corollary you cite requires $R$ to be an integral domain, which is **not** the case here. $\mathbb Z_9$ has a zero-divisor ($3 \cdot 3=0$).

Being a unit is the same as having an inverse.

So there should exist some polynomial $g(x) \in \mathbb Z_9[x]$ such that $(1+3x)g(x)=1$.

Try to write out what this means and find this polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find a polynomial which when multiplied by $1+3x$ gives $1$ modulo 9.

You can try to guess with something simple: $a+bx$. So you want $(1+3x)(a+bx)\equiv1$ modulo 9.

Multiply this out and you'll get some equations for $a$ and $b$ modulo 9. You may find at this point that you can guess $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would come up with a solution.

Formally
$$\frac{1}{1+3x}=\frac{1}{1-(-3x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-3x)^n=1+(-3x)+9x^2-27x^3\dots=1-3x$$ when $9$ is set to zero. It is relatively easy to show such logic will always work in cases like this (when the first coefficient is a unit and the rest are nilpotent) and showing the more general characterization of units of polynomial rings (see the first couple exercises in Atiyah-Macdonald) can be done using a similar argument.

Answer (score 1):

$(1+3x)(1-3x) = 1-9x^2$. Using congruence mod 9 and it's done